# General method to select first row from every group in DataTable, give a List of grouping column

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I can use this code to get every first row from each group (group by ID) from DataTable:

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("ID")).Select(g => g.First()).CopyToDataTable();
```

But it group only ID and I have to hardcode it myself.

I wonder if there is general method, that put in a list of column name to group.

```
public DataTable GetFirstFromEachGroupBy(List<string> GroupByColumns)
{
  dt = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(GroupByColumns).Select(g => g.First()).CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: How do you define the "first row"? Usually a col named "ID" will be unique within a table, is that not the case in your example?

Comment: This is just an example. Sometimes, we don't have Unique ID to group like this.

Comment: GroupBy multicolumns may be more different than what you think. When you group by `ID` and `Name`, the `ID` will be grouped first, then in each group of `ID`, the `Name` will be grouped. That means you will have some groups of `ID` and each group of `ID` will have some groups of `Name`. If so, what's the `Select(g=>g.First())` applied on? Anyway the end result before calling `CopyToDataTable` should be an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a computed column to the table that concatenates the fields, then group by that column:

```
string newcolExpression = @"' ' + " + string.Join(" + ",GroupByColumns) ; // prepend a space to ensure string concatenation
// e.g. "' ' + ID1 + ID2"

dt.Columns.Add("GroupBy",typeof(string),newcolExpression);

dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
       .GroupBy(r => r["GroupBy"])
       .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r["PK"]).First())
       .CopyToDataTable();

dt.Columns.Remove("GroupBy");
```